# Javascript DOM - how do I display my object into a string?

Tags: javascript, json, dom

how do I display my object into a string? I get the error message:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')
at HTMLButtonElement.detailClickHandler

```
  function detailClickHandler(e) {
    let details = e.target
    // get the relative id
    let hero = details.closest('.card').dataset.id
    console.log(hero)

    // display hero description
    let description = document.createElement('p');
    description.innerHTML = hero
    detailsContainer.appendChild(description)

  }
```

above in my init function I am calling the html:

```
//globals
let heroes
let hero
let theData = {}
let detailsContainer
let cardsContainer


function init () {
  cardsContainer = document.querySelector(".cards")
  detailsContainer = document.querySelector(".detail")
```

Comment: Is it possible that the DOM isn't loaded yet? You should put all your functions inside window.onload

Comment: The error message says that `detailsContainer` is `null` but you haven't shown us how that variable is defined.

Comment: I have tried your guys input thank you very much but I haven't made it work yet, I updated the info

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Answer (score -1):

Your detailsContainer is not set.  Try `details` or `details.parentElement`.
Or do a DOM search for it.

```
// detailsContainer.innerHTML = '';
details.innerHTML = '';
// or
details.parentElement.innerHTML = '';
// or
document.getElementById('#theElement').innerHTML = ''
```

Comment: My focus is a little lower, I have changed some details and hopefully it helps drawing a picture with my problem.

Comment: So `document.querySelector(".detail")` is not finding your element.  You need to show use your DOM elements.